# May a husband make a suit in beis din on behalf of his wife?

Tags: family-members

If a wife is uncomfortable suing someone that owes her alone money, but she is willing to be a witness, may the husband file suit against the person that wronged her?

Comment: How can she be a witness for him? She's related to him.

Comment: Aren't only blood relatives  disqualified? Sanhedrin chapter 3 lists which blood relatives are included. However, women in general are disqualified.
Are women disqualified as eidei beirur ?